# How a programmers solve the dilemma of using old variables instead of new variables?

Tags: optimization, coding-style

For example:

... some code

```
int sizeOfSomeObject = someObject.length();
```

... some code, sizeOfSomeObject is not need anymore

now I need other int variable for other action(for example, for position in some object), and i have the dilemma: create a new variable or use sizeOfSomeObject for this. In the first case I will keep readability, but lose performance. In the second case - on the contrary. What usually do programmers in this situation?

Comment: What makes you think you'll lose performance?  Your compiler is almost certainly smart enough to "do the right thing" in this case.

Answer (score 4):

> In the first case I will keep readability, but lose performance. In the second case - on the contrary.

So did you benchmark it? I suspect no, you didn't. Most modern compilers do a lot of agressive analysis during register allocation, so if the optimizer perceives that there's a variable that's not used anymore, but there's a new variable of the same type, it will just merge the two variables to the same memory region or processor register. No need to worry about performance penalties.

---

And anyway, don't do premature optimization (which this is). In 90% of the cases, readability is more important than "performance".

All in all, go ahead and create a new variable with an appropriate, different, descriptive name. And just for fun, compile this version and the version in which you used the same variable name, and look at the generated assembly (or bytecode, or...) - and find out that they're **identical.**

Answer (score 1):

I would use different named variables for different things.

In terms of something like this, I don't think just one variable would cause a massive performance hit.  In most languages you have the option to clear variables from memory in some way when they are no longer in use, so I would recommend doing that so that the code means something to you or others when read at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can use blocks for objects to be destroyed as soon as they are not needed anymore:

```
void some_function () {
   {
      MyClass c;
      // ... here we use c ...
   }
   // now c has been destroyed
   {
      MyClass d;
      // ... here we use d ...
   }
   // now d has been destroyed
}
```

In your example (with `int` variables), there is no reason to worry about *performance*. The worst thing that could probably happen is memory for two variables being used instead of one, but (i) that's negligible and (ii) `int`'s will probably live in a CPU register, anyway. If you *really* worry, use the block approach for your `int` example.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how often such an int would be initialized. If it's not in some hugely nested for loop, most (all) programmers will go for the first. Besides, most modern programming languages have a garbage collector, which cleans up left over objects.

Comment: "If it's not in some hugely nested for loop" - note that today's compilers will be smart enough to move loop variables outside the loop, so that allocation doesn't happen upon each iteration.

Comment: You're welcome. A tiny detail that can make some big benefits, it's worth knowing about.

Answer (score 0):

Decent compiler will optimize out your second variable, so that shouldn't be an issue.

That said, there are situations where variable reuse makes sense. E.g., you might have some variable that holds a generic output populated from call to some external API. According to the context and parameters passed to the API you'll process the data differently but it's probably better (more readable etc.) to reuse the same data variable.

For example, something like this:

```
void* data = getSomeData(params);
//process data
//change params
data = getSomeData(params);
//process data
//change params
data = getSomeData(params);
```